# Find intersected points between plane and point cloud

Tags: matlab

I would like to find all the points from the intersection between a plane and a point cloud. The plane should be variable in thickness to include points that are not directly intersected. The following figure shows my current status.

[image]

As you can see my point cloud has the shape of a cylinder and the plane I created intersects the point cloud on one side along the z-axis. To find the intersected points I used [this](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/482984-extract-planes-from-point-cloud) code as a basis. The red circles in the figure represent the intersected points but unfortunately they are not at the place where my plane is. I tried to change the part of the code where the distance to the plane is defined and I also tried to change the plot of the intersected points but I couldn't solve the problem. My code looks as follows.

```
x1 = ptCloud(:,1);
y1 = ptCloud(:,2);
z1 = ptCloud(:,3);

% set up plane using 3 points 
p0 = [0 0 min(z1)];
p1 = [min(x1) 0 min(z1)];
p2 = [0 0 max(z1)];

n = cross(p0-p1,p0-p2);
n = n/norm(n);

% Plane equation
% a(x-x0) + b(y-y0) + c(z-z0) = 0 
F = @(Y,Z) p0(1) + n(2)*(Y-p0(2)) + n(3)*(Z-p0(3));

[y0,z0] = meshgrid([min(x1(:)) 0],[min(z1(:)) max(z1(:))]);
x0 = F(y0,z0);

    % find distance to plane for each point
    % (using the same formula)
FDIST = @(X,Y,Z) sum(n.*(p0-[X Y Z]));
    D = arrayfun(FDIST,x1(:),y1(:),z1(:),'uni',false);
D1 = cell2mat(D);
mindist = 1.3;                          % minumum distance to plane in mm to both sides 
ind = abs(D1) < mindist;

% Plot the results
 mplot = @(p,s) plot3(p(1),p(2),p(3),s);
  plot3(x1(:),y1(:),z1(:),'.b')               % all data 

hold on
plot3(x1(ind),y1(ind),z1(ind),'or')        % points belong to plane
    % original points
mplot(p1,'^k')
mplot(p2,'^k')
mplot(p0,'^k')

surf(x0,y0,z0,'FaceAlpha',0.5);          % plane

% Labelling of the axes
xlabel('X(mm)')
ylabel('Y(mm)')
zlabel('Z(mm)')
title('Plane in point cloud')

hold off

axis equal
```

My x1,y1,z1 values are 114964x1 coordinates.
Does anyone knows what I have to change in my code to solve my problem or does someone maybe have a better way to find the intersected points? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Determine your plan equation and add your constraints. Then check which points satisfie the equation and the constraints.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My vectors are p0=[0,0,0]; p1=[-74,0,0]; p2=[0,0,690.18]; n=[0,1,0], so my plane equation is 1*Y=0 and my constraints are y0=[-76.968,0] and z0=[0,690.18]. To check the points that satisfy my equation do I have to write another Function or how can I do that in MATLAB?

Comment: I was able to solve it myself.

Comment: good to hear that !